# i want to create a php blog system without database

Tags: php, html, css, xml

i am creating an blog system where i can use only static files . I have    section where i am creating a new post and i write it on a text file like        this:

**new_post. php**

```
<form id=" form1" name="form1" method="post" action="writeblog.php">
<p> 
<label>TITLE: </label><input type="text" name="title"/>
<label for="body"> Body: </label>
 <textarea name="body" cols=50 rows=10></textarea>
 <br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="POST"/>
 </form>
```

**writeblog.php**

```
<?php
$out = fopen("blog.txt","a");
if(!$out){
header('Location: new_post.php');
exit;
}

$title=$_POST[title];
$body=$_POST[body];
$body=str_replace("\n"," ",$body);
fputs($out,"\n");
fputs($out,date("m/j/y h:i \n ",time()));
fputs($out,"$title\n\n\n");
fputs($out,"$body\n\n\n\n\n");
fclose($out);
header('Location: new_post.php');
exit;
?>
```

I need some help with how I can work with just one post from the file delete it or edit it insert in on page.

Comment: Did you consider using a structured file format, i.e. XML or JSON for storing your blog posts? An alternative approach is taken by https://jekyllrb.com/ which uses static Markdown files for  blog entries.

Comment: i don't really know how to work with them

Comment: this might be a good start for JSON http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php - maybe starting with a good tutorial for PHP might be a good first thing to learn? https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php - just one recommendation

Comment: any reason you're not using a database? Using text files are so much work, especially when it comes to editing/maintenance.

Comment: Because I am not allowed to use a database it's a project for school